# Python Django - Select Choice is not Valid

Tags: python, django

When I want to save my form on a new CharFields (with Choices), Django tell me that the Select choice is not valid.
When I take another Choice list which works with other models, it does work normally.

Models.py:

```py
class productsdefinition(models.Model):
    Products = models.CharField(max_length=Lenght200, default='NA')
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=Lenght10, choices=Utilities_CSP.PRODENG_CHOICES)
    Tester = models.ForeignKey(tester, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Board = models.ForeignKey(board, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    TestProgram = models.CharField(max_length=Lenght200, default='')
    ProgramLoad = models.ForeignKey(ProgramLoad, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ListProgramEG = Utilities_CSP.ExtractProgEG()
    Probecard = models.CharField(verbose_name='Probe Card',max_length=Lenght200, choices=ListProgramEG, null=True)
    ProgramEG = models.CharField(verbose_name='Program EG',max_length=Lenght200, choices=ListProgramEG, null=True)
```

forms.py:

```py
class ProducDefForm(forms.ModelForm):
    global tempfield
    i = 0
    tempfield = []
    
    for var in list(vars(productsdefinition()).keys()):
        if i <= 1:
            pass
        elif var == "Date_added":
            pass
        elif var == "LastModified":
            pass
        elif var.find("_id") != -1:
            var = var.replace("_id","")
            tempfield.append(str(var))
        else:
            tempfield.append(str(var))
        i = i + 1
    class Meta:
        model = productsdefinition
        fields = tempfield

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProducDefForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ListProbecard = Utilities_CSP.ExtractProgEG()
        self.fields['Probecard'].choices = ListProbecard
```

So my field ProgramEG works fine, but when I try to put the list (of choices) to ensure that the field Probecard work, it stops working and it tells me `Select Choice in not valid,....`.
Do you have any idea where the error can be? Is it in the table of the database?

EDIT:
I solve my problem: i change the model fields of th Probecard
def **init** (self, *args, **kwargs):
super(ProducDefForm, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
ListProbecard = Utilities_CSP.ExtractListCAPChoice()
self.fields['Probecard'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ListProbecard)

Thankd for your time of view.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `tempfield` things?

Comment: Hi, With my tempfield, i try to recover all fields of my model wihtout the _id behind some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem: i change the model fields of th Probecard def init (self, *args, **kwargs): super(ProducDefForm, self).init(*args, **kwargs) ListProbecard = Utilities_CSP.ExtractListCAPChoice() self.fields['Probecard'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ListProbecard)